# WriteableBitmap.Render changing color in the image

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, render, writeablebitmap

So I am trying to save a png of a UserControl to use as a tile. The code that i am using is

```
SquareTile sq = new SquareTile();
sq.Measure(new Size(336,336));
sq.Arrange(new Rect(0,0,336,336));
RenderExtensions.SaveToFile(sq);
```

And the RenderExtension Class looks like this

```
public static class RenderExtensions
{
    public static bool SaveToFile(this UIElement visualTreeElement)
    {
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(336, 336);
        wb.Render(visualTreeElement, null);
        wb.Invalidate();
        return wb.SaveToFile();
    }

    public static bool SaveToFile(this WriteableBitmap renderTargetBitmap)
    {
        try
        {
            string fname = "Shared/ShellContent/SquareTile.png";

            //StorageFile liveTileImageFile = localFolder.CreateFile("/Shared/ShellContent/SquareTile.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            ExtendedImage ei = new ExtendedImage();
            byte[] result = new byte[renderTargetBitmap.Pixels.Length * sizeof(int)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(renderTargetBitmap.Pixels, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
            ei.SetPixels(336,336,result);

            if (ei != null)
            {
                IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                using (isf)
                {
                    if (!isf.DirectoryExists("Shared")) { isf.CreateDirectory("Shared"); }
                    if (!isf.DirectoryExists("Shared/ShellContent")) { isf.CreateDirectory("Shared/ShellContent"); }
                    if (isf.FileExists(fname)) { isf.DeleteFile(fname); }

                    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fname, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, isf))
                    {
                        ei.WriteToStream(stream, fname);
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Now the tile looks like this (Note background color has some transparency)
[image]

And if I add the same UserControl in a grid, it actually looks like this 
[image]

here is the original image that this usercontrol is showing

[image]

You can see how red has turned blue even though the image is not transparent there.
Why is this happening?

**Update:**
I also tried a different image with only three colors red blue and yellow. turns out only red and blue are getting switched.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like WriteableBitmap and ExtendedImage expect their bytes to be in different formats. Probably BRGA (for WriteableBitmap) vs. RGBA (for ExtendedImage).

Unless you can specify the order on the ExtendedImage to match the WriteableBitmap you'll need to swizzle the bytes rather than just copying them straight over so that the colours line up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have managed to swap the red and blue using this function

```
private static byte[] convertArray(int[] array)
    {
        byte[] newarray = new byte[array.Length * 4];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {

            newarray[i * 4] = (byte)(array[i] >> 16); 
            newarray[i * 4 + 1] = (byte)(array[i] >> 8); 
            newarray[i * 4 + 2] = (byte)(array[i]); 
            newarray[i * 4 + 3] = (byte)(array[i] >> 24); 

        }
        return newarray;
    }
```

so now I am not using

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(renderTargetBitmap.Pixels, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
```

to convert int[] of WriteableBitmap.Pixels to byte[] required by ExtendedImage

Comment: How about using [`BitmapEncoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx)? You wouldn't need a third party library, nor doing this conversion, and it's faster, I think. It wasn't available before 8.1, but I see the question is marked with wp8.1 tag, so you might want to give it a try.

Comment: Is that available in silverlight or runtime

Comment: It's available in both